# Using all available space with JInternalFrames in a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

i want to build the following layout:

```
+--------------+-------+
|              |       |
|              |   O   |
|    GAME      |   P   |
|              |   T   |
|              |       |
+--------------+-------+
|                      |
|      CONDITIONS      |
|                      |
+--------------+-------+
```

while each component should be a frame

I decided to use the `GridBagLayout` and it kind of works:
[image: What i have so far]

The problem is quite obvious: The frames a way to small

Here's the sample code for one of the frames (they are nearly all the same): As you see they do nothing yet

```
public class Game extends JInternalFrame {

    public Game(){
        super("Game");
    }

}
```

And here is how i build up the layout:

```
//set dimension (x, y)
this.setSize(900, 600);
//deny resizing
this.setResizable(false);
//set position (x: top, y: left)
this.setLocation(300, 300);
[....]
    this.options = new Options();
    this.conditions = new Conditions();
    this.game = new Game();
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    this.add(this.options, c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;

    this.add(this.game, c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 2;

    this.add(this.conditions, c);

    this.options.setVisible(true);
    this.conditions.setVisible(true);
    this.game.setVisible(true);
```

So my questions are

1) How do i get the frames to use the full space of the window
2) How do i make them in diffrent size (as `this.options.setSize(...)` is not working?)

PS: Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/TSWyyi7v

Comment: `Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/TSWyyi7v` - I'm doubt in that, this isn't way how this site works, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about one JInternalFrame and issue with GBC,  [your SSCCE can be based on one of my posts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20114198/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel you are right this is not the full code, but it's the windows full code (forgot to write that)

Comment: anyway here is a compilable and executable minified example http://pastebin.com/sZqu8q56 (already a bit improved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your picture a BorderLayout would be easier:

```
setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(options, BorderLayout.EAST);
add(conditions, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```