# Arranging 2 JPanels on one JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

I went through many tutorials and the official Guide for Layout Managers, but I can't find the right answer for my question. 
I am planning to code a little game and for that, I created a JPanel to draw and plan to add another one for the scoreBoard. The scoreBoard should always keep like 1/5 of the screen but when I try different Layout Managers, it seems to ignore the preferred sizes.
Can anyone tell me how to arrange the 2 panel to be next to each other and one fills 1/5 of the Frame and the other one 4/5?
Thanks for your help.

I've build a more simple code to test this:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1000,1000);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);
    panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

    frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What layout accepts percentages instead of values in swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114174/what-layout-accepts-percentages-instead-of-values-in-swing)

Comment: Also look into possibly using a 3rd party layout, the [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), which I think can handle this sort of thing.

Comment: `The scoreBoard should always keep like 1/5 of the screen` - why? The scoreboard should be the size it needs to be based on the components added to it. You can influence the size by adding a [Swing Border](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) to the panel. Maybe use an EmptyBorder. Then as the frame increases the extra space goes to the game board. Or maybe you should even make the frame a fixed size by use `setResizable( false );`

Comment: None of the standard JDK layouts support the type of layout you want. Do specify a layout be a fixed percentage you can use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). `, it seems to ignore the preferred sizes.` - why would you say that? What happens. I would expect both panels to be the same size (not 1/5 and 4/5) since you give them each the same size. The CENTER panel will then adjust as you change the size of the frame, since that is the rules of the BorderLayout which is the default layout for a frame.