# Using GridBagConstraints for percentage based size?

Tags: java, swing, resize, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to make a JFrame that has two seperate JPanels on it. The left one should be 70% of the window size and the right one should be 30%.

I could probably accomplish this by overriding the setSize method in JFrame and then setting the size of each panel to a percentage of this, however I assume there is a simpler approach.

I've tried using GridBagConstraints to achieve this, however when adding components to my right panel it alters the size of my left one, even if those components never extend 30% in size.

Example;

This is how it should look

[image: This is how it should look]

I've tried simply doing this;

```
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    gbc.weightx = 0.7;
    add(new JPanel(), gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.weightx = 0.3;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
    add(new JPanel(), gbc);
```

But that doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No standard layouts allow you to do this. Check out camickr's "relative layout", the link in his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114174/what-layout-accepts-percentages-instead-of-values-in-swing), and then up-vote his answer.

Comment: *"The left one should be 70% of the window size and the right one should be 30%."* **..Why?** Explain what is in the two areas that makes any sense for them to have a fixed percentage of the available width.

Comment: `Am I doing something wrong?` - the weightx property is only used to allocate "extra space". So first each component is given space at its preferred size. If there is any extra space that is allocated in the 70/30 ratio.

Comment: `JSplitPane` has `setDividerLocation()` and `setResizeWeight()`.